# Get Icon info from the executable file?

Tags: windows, icons, gdi, winapi

I'm trying to get the icon from the .exe file using the following APIs:
**SHGetFileInfoW**() **SHGetImageList**() and from the *ImageList* thus obtained I read the icon by calling **GetIcon**().

When the color depth of the machine is set to 32bit I get the 32bit color icon. The issue is when I change the machine's color depth to 24 or 16 bit then I get a 16bit color icon and this image seems to be corrupted.

I also checked for the list of available icons in some of the common windows applications (notepad, paint etc) and some of the office applications, none of had 16bit or 24 bit color icons.

What would be the best way to get the proper icons from the executable file ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can load exe's using LoadLibraryEx, and then extract the icons using LoadImage - or - if you want direct access to the icons data: FindResource, LoadResource, LockResource will give you a pointer to the icon's resources bits.

Comment: The exe could have a bunch of ICON images and how do I choose a desired icon say the one with color depth 32 ?

Comment: If you are using LoadImage, then it will choose the correct one based on your parameters to LoadImage. If you are using LoadResource then you need to know that each Icon file corresponds to an RT_ICON_GROUP resource, which in turn points to individual RT_ICON resources, one for each devise depth supported in the ico file. Something like that.